# Not able to load local .xml file through Jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a sample web application on my local machine. I want to make ajax call to an `.xml` file which is on my local machine.

It is not working in any browsers at all.
When i try to see in the Network tab of Chrome it display that `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/somefolder/finishers.xml?_=1392713504397.` No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

May be this is possible duplicate question, but I am new to Jquery.
Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "finishers.xml",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){}    
});
```

Please help me how to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: may i know which browser you are using. Try latest version of firefox to check in local else check it on webserver

Answer (score 2):

This is because you run the code in the local machine (without running under a web server).

Put your code under a web server(like apache) and try again.

Comment: FOR EVERYONE IN THE FUTURE Reading Head First jQuery, this is the reason your finishers.xml file is not showing up in the network tab. I ran the same file in WAMP server, and accessed the file using localhost/ch8/index.html, and it now shows up in the network tab.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get has nothing to do with the JavaScript you created but its the access of using that data (also called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea)). As the api (server) does not know your client you are not allowed to use the data.

1) A solution is to make the page you are using for calling the (web)api is in the same domain as your (web)api. In that case they share the same domain and so you are allowed to use the same data.

2) Another solution (cross domain) for your problem is to make your server aware of your domain and that your domain is a valid domain to use the data. I don't know what kind of language you use for the the (web)api, but you have to configure the endpoint it will return a header with

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'Your domain of the calling client here'"
```

To try if this is indeed your problem you can also try this as a return header

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

**NOTE:** Be aware that you will NOT use this in production as you are actually saying that everybody can use this (web)api.

Comment: As you've mentioned in first way, if both files share same domain it should allow me to use the data.That's why i have raised this question.All filese(html, .js, .xml) files are in same folder and still i am not able to access it.

Comment: Same folder is not equal to same domain. If you have a (web)api via and you access your html file via the local folder (opening by dubble click or something), the domains are different. If you have an (web)api running (example: http://localhost/mywebapi) you also need to access your html file via the same way (http://localhost/Mypage.html) to make the first option work. I can see in the url of your post that you are opening the file directly from the D drive..

Comment: Thanks for information, it is working now without web server.In IE and mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a result of a request being made from your client code to a non-existent server. Your first option is to deploy your website to a hosting platform. This is, however, a production activity and would not be necessary to quickly confirm the feature you have implemented.

A quick fix is to run a webserver on your local machine by installing python, navigating to the root of the project directory in terminal and running this command.

```
python -m http.server
```

You can then navigate to the appropriate localhost port and enter your web application via the index.html file