# making and appending a substring from getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, substring, getelementbyid

I am trying to make a news preview from a separate file (text.html) I want to be able to just display the first 100 characters of a div (id="news"). I don't want to use Ajax or Php. Here is my code, not sure how to make it work, thanks guys.

```
<body onload="home()">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        function home() {
            var x = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html" data="text.html"></object>';
            var pre = x.substring(0,5);
            alert(pre);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: AJAX or an iframe is the best options here, AJAX being the preferable. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: Is `test.html` on the same domain?

Comment: I kept getting this error, so i googled it and found that you couldn't load a local file and my file is local. This was the error I was getting
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Hillary/Desktop/Mums%20website/text.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: RGraham, both files (text.html) and (test.html) are in the same folder test.html is where i want to load text.html

Comment: @DanPaull There are extensions for most browsers that allows you to do this if you just want to try it out, but you have to solve it some other way if you want to publish your site.

Comment: @hochas how do i manage to get around this, I have looked for a long time and can't work it out

Comment: @DanPaull Use a [local web server](http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-web-server-all-platforms/), then you'll be able to use AJAX. As Rory says, this is the way to go

Comment: You say you don't want to use AJAX, but you are using XMLHttpRequest that is the keystone of AJAX. Now, do you have these files running on a server or locally? Your request is "file:///C:/Users/Hillary/Desktop/Mums%20website/text.html" that is local. You should be referring to the file within the server (using relative/absolute paths) instead of referring to the local path of the file as that is generally not allowed (for security reasons)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I have all of my files running locally. Should I look into exploring running them on a server? if so how hard is it to understand/ learn?

Comment: If your problem is just to show the first 100 characters of the text, you can achieve it by the CSS style text-overflow: ellipsis . You can't calculate exactly 100 chars but simply adjust the width of the div to some acceptable width.

Comment: @DanPaull, maybe. I think the issue might be there. When you load the file do you use a relative path (i.e.: ./filename.html) or do you use its local path (c:/mydir/filename.html)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I am using the relative path, should I be using the local path?

Comment: I think the real issue is that you are running the files without a server. Check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848540/not-able-to-load-local-xml-file-through-jquery-ajax-call, and maybe try to run the files from a local server instead and let us know if it works